# WordPress AMP Integration

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I just installed the AMP from Automatic in my WordPress site. When I load the page I have to type /amp after the link in order to display the amp page/post.
Questions are: how can I display the page automatically without having to type the /amp ?
how can I show the other posts that I have on the site?

Hope you can give me a starting point since I am a bit lost.
Here my site : http://www.demosite.burnnotice.co.za/

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to type /amp and the end in order to view the amp version in desktop. Once you have properly implement AMP to your website and Google crawls the website, the amp pages will be shown to the visitors on Google Search.

You will only be able to see amp pages if its properly set up.AMP is only for mobile platforms. Make sure you have implemented AMP properly:
https://www.techtipshacks.com/setup-amp-wordpress.html

Also i would recommend adding a Menu, Related posts etc to AMP pages as the plugin by automattic is having limited functionalities:
https://www.techtipshacks.com/add-menu-related-posts-social-icons-for-amp.html

Answer (score 1):

Install "AMP Validator" extension to chrome