# AMP for WordPress: Home page /amp only displays right column widget

Tags: wordpress, accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

When I use the /amp suffix to check AMP Pages it works normally, but when I do it on our home page (www.oursausalito.com) it shows just one widget from the right hand column, despite the amp content being formatted the same way as the other pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress AMP Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258749/wordpress-amp-integration)